# mgcv and cyclic smoothers, am I doing it right?

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

TLDR: Need advice on implementation of model, particularly cyclical smoothers

I'm constructing a model that has around 3 months of daily data (a few days missing) for a response variable that falls between 0 and 400 (**MR_dist**; around 800 data points). This is representative of mean distance in meters of sound propagation (should mention that each datapoint is taken from the midpoint of a series of logistic regression models).

I want to know how this variable is influenced by a variety of environmental variables, some of these relationships will definitely be non-linear. As a result I've decided to use mgcv in r to fit the model.

The explanatory variables are both continuous and factors. Here is the head of the data:
[image]

They are:

date = date on which the measurement is taken

section = categorical variable of 11 levels indicating site at which measurements were taken

habitat = factor variable indicating whether the measurement falls under one of four habitat types

mean_wh = continuous variable of wave height

mean_wind_speed = continuous variable of wind speed

tidal_reach = tide strength on that day

I've thus far fitted the following model:

```
m = mgcv::bam(MR_dist ~ section +
                s(date, k = 15, bs = 'cc') +
                s(mean_wh, k = 3) +
                s(mean_wind_speed, k = 3) +
                s(tidal_reach, k = 15, bs = 'cc'), data = df, method = 'REML')
```

I decided to fit date and tidal reach using a cyclical smoothers, and after some initial visualization I've decided to set quite low k-values for some of the vars. As you may note habitat isn't included in the above model as it was causing problems with outputs (I have no idea why):

[image]

These are just the model outputs:

[image]

I have lots of questions, but main ones are:

1. Have I specified the model somewhat correctly, including the use of the cyclical smoothers?
2. Why is it that if I included habitat (which is basically a factor which breaks down section into four groups) I have missing outputs?
3. To the best of my knowledge the relationship between some of the explanatory variables and the response seems linear, is this an issue if I use mgcv (quite clearly some of the relationship are non-linear, such as date), do I need to add something to say they are linear (I've just kept the k value low)?

Thank you.

update 26/01/2021

I've decided to drop habitat from the model as it was making things difficult to interpret. Site is still within the model and it represents an 11 level categorical variable. I've also dropped the cyclic smoothers as I had misunderstood their use. Here is the model structure as it stands in equation form:

[image]

and here is the code used in mgcv:

```
m1 = mgcv::bam(MR_dist ~s_site +
                        s(date, bs = "gp", k = 20) +
                        s(mean_wh) +
                        s(mean_wind_speed, k = 15) +
                        s(daily_rain, k = 15) +
                        s(ship_count) +
                        s(tidal_range) + 
                        s(mean_wh, by = s_site) +
                        s(mean_wind_speed, by = s_site) +
                        s(daily_rain, by = s_site) +
                        s(ship_count, by = s_site)+
                        s(tidal_range, by = s_site),
                        data = df, method = 'fREML', select = TRUE)
```

Any feedback on the structure would be really appreciated. Does this seems suitable? Another change I've made was to use a gaussian process smooth as base function for date (given there might be temporal autocorrelation in response). Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm confused as to why you'd fit 3 day as a cyclic smoother when you only have three months of data? The point to cyclic smooths is that there is a natural point that is both small and large that are essentially the same thing because the covariate space wraps around on itself; think wind direction, aspect, and day of year where you have observations from throughout the year. The reason we often model day of year or month as cyclic is that we have data from January and December and these should wrap around to be similar to one another.

The same point can be made about making the smooth of tidal strength cyclic; the values of tidal strength don't wrap around like wind direction in degrees. I appreciate that the value taken by tidal strength might vary seasonally or cyclically *in time*, but tidal strength itself isn't cyclic.

I also wouldn't set `k` so low for the other two smooths; unless you know those effects have very little non-linearity, it is better to `k` a bit higher and let the penalty work to remove un-needed wiggliness.

Re Q2; the missing level is bound up in the intercept because of how the model is parameterised. The reference level (the missing habitat) is represented by the intercept and the coefficients fo the other three habitats represent deviations of those habitats from the reference level (habitat).

Comment: (1of2) Gavin, thank you for the useful insight! I was misunderstanding the use of the cyclic smooths. I guess then it would then make sense if I had a whole year of data? 

I'm a little confused as to how to choose the type of smooths in mgcv. Given your comments, what type of smooth would you use for something like tide that have daily cycles? 

Re Q2. I was referring to the 0 estimates and the NAs. I was aware that the missing level is in the intercept.

I did put higher k values but I was having issues with the number of covariate combinations being lower...

Comment: (2of2) -than the specified maximum degrees of freedom, and the highest value I could use didn't seem to influence the shape.

Comment: Yes; if you had a full year of data a cyclic smooth would be appropriate. Remember the smooth is being used to model the effect of tidal height on the response not how the independent variables vary in time. As such you should just use a standard smooth (the default is a thin plate spline, but a cubic regression spline would be a good basic choice if you have a lot of data). Re the `NA`s, sorry I misread your question; the `NA`s are due to aliasing where you can't identify the particular effects because those effects are already included in the model. I suspect what is going on is that...

Comment: ...once habitat is in the model, it explains all of some of the section effects, in the sense that some sections must only occur in a single habitat?

Comment: Yes, the section are basically grouped within the habitat variable and these are essentially discrete (i.e. only appear in one habitat). Thus for instance you may have section (1,2,3) in the inner habitat category. Cool, also with regards to the k-values, I guess I set them as high as I can before the max-deg freedom issue then?

Comment: Also, with the gam.check output (added image) I have a couple of significant p values. Should I be worried? My understanding was that if edf is quite a bit lower than K then it's not an issue, is this correct?

Comment: You should add content to answers just to reply/comment. If it is pertinent add it to your question.

Comment: So you can't estimate unique effects for those levels of `section`. Re `k`, not really, I mean you could do that but it would be very inefficient. Instead think about the range of effects you would expect; for tidal height I can't imaging the effect would be more complex than something with say 5-10 EDF so leave `k = 10` (the default). You could maybe go higher with the `k` for `date`, but doubt you need more than 20. Then check the `gam.check()` output.

Comment: Re the `ga,.check()` output, that (EDF << k') is only a guide. One complication is that if k' is too low to start with, the penalization could move EDF well away from k' when in fact a higher `k` is needed. Also, all else equal a basis of size 10 or richer in terms of say ~5 EDF functions than a basis of size 5 is. I would fix the cyclic basis issues, fit model, then increase `k` and refit and see if the smooths change or the EDF of the fits increases.

Comment: Sorry I tried to add it to question...and added to your answer by mistake. But won't let me edit it out unless I insert an additional 6 words. Ok I'll try what you mentioned and will post an update. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118632/discussion-between-dasr-and-gavin-simpson).